# Discard changes and Add new record Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6, entity, entity-framework-5

On form, I have text controls binded to BindingList that is DbContext.TableName.Local.Load()

I have used DbContext.Product.Include("Orders").Load()
method to load Products with Orders in eager loading way.

I have button New on form. When I click it, it should show empty controls on form so that user can enter it.

I tried with Clear() method on Local DbContext, but when I used SaveChanges, it adds new record but also deletes record as it remembered it that I cleared it.

Note: my controls are binded using BindingList. So how to be able to add new record, without deleting previous.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be positive without seeing your code, but it sounds like you might benefit from a greater separation between your presentation logic and your database model.

Perhaps, instead of binding directly to your dbContext objects, you could bind to some Properties, which you could then use to populate your entity framework objects.

Again, without a code example it's hard to say for sure. 
Also, is this winforms or WPF?